# How to write the column names with Hadoop Mapreduce?

Tags: python-2.7, mapreduce

I am running a Mapreduce using Hadoop streaming API - writing mapper and reducer in python. My questions are about formatting the final output (reducer output) and few others. Can I write column names (is it called column qualifier?)?  Also how to maintain the column space to be constant when each row entry has different width?

As the each line in the input file is processed, is it possible to set a counter and increment it - how? Mapper does not have to send a key - just the value?

I hear log4j is used to log errors - what needs to be done in the reducer or log4j to get it logged in log4j - will it also work on python - otherwise, how to get it logged?

Comment: I don't know Hadoop so I can't help there, but consider rewriting/reformatting your question to make it more clear what you're asking. Try to ask only one question at a time and include any relevant code of what you've tried and where the issue is. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Done thanks - appreciate it.